# How to insert a character before first number in a string?

Tags: python, regex, string, substitution

I have a Python 3 program that takes commands such as `!down3` or `!up48`. I wish to insert a character (the letter x) between the numbers and the rest of the command(e.g. `!upx48` or `!downx3`). The letter x must only be inserted at that location.

The commands will only be "up" "down" "left" or "right" and the number will be a maximum of 2 digits (and an integer.)

What is the simplest way of doing this?

Comment: You need to have a `set` of all commands. It gets more complicated if `up` and `ups` are both commands.

Comment: Yeah, the commands will only ever be up, down, left or right. And the number wil always be 2 digits

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can loop over the command and insert the `'x'`:

```
def insert_x(command):
    for i, c in enumerate(command):
        if c.isdigit():
            break
    return command[:i] + 'x' + command[i:]
```

Examples:

```
>>> insert_x('!down3')
'!downx3'

>>> insert_x('!up48')
'!upx48'
```

Comment: This works, but doesn't seem to integrate well with the rest of the code (the "x" is removed.) since it works on its own I wil accept this answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regex:

```
>>> li=["!down3", "!up48"]
>>> [re.sub(r'^(\D)(up|down|left|right)(\d+)',r'\1\2x\3', s) for s in li]
['!downx3', '!upx48']
```

You can also be pickier to only match if it is the entire string and only two digits (as you described):

```
>>> [re.sub(r'^(\D)(up|down|left|right)(\d{1,2})$',r'\1\2x\3', s) for s in li]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
command = "!down3"

indexes = [i for i, a in enumerate(command) if a.isdigit()]

command = list(command)
x = "somevalue"
command.insert(indexes[0], x)

print ''.join(command)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

def insertX(s):
    split = re.split('(\d.*)',s)
    return "x".join(split[:-1])

s = "!down354"
insertX(s)
```

Results:

```
!downx354
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using this a bunch of times maybe a dict is the answer:

```
cmds = {d+str(i):d+'x'+str(i) for i in range(10,100) for d in ['up','down','left','right']}
print cmds
```